# MSI Package hangs-up when calculating disk space

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, diskspace

In my team we prepared an msi installer package for our application. Package is made in WIX contains custom UI, call custom actions from C# library and almost everything works fine except one thing: calculating required disk space. On this stage whole installer hangs up from time to time, especially when client testing it :( We have the same problems on developing machine, but restarting installer helps, so this error is quite random.
I was googling a little bit and found two workarounds, all based on command line parameters:

**msiexec /i filename.msi** (change state messages handling)

and

**msiexec /package  /qr** (starting package with limited UI)

unfortunately its not a solution for me, because installer has to working without passing extra parameters to it when user want to install application :(

I'll be appreciate for any clue in my investigation :)

Comment: See what's there in the verbose log. Run your MSI like this: msiexec /i filename.msi LOGVERBOSE=1 /l*+v install.log

Comment: Everything is correct (no errors, warning, etc), except that installer hanging-up on disk costing message :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to read this blog post:

[It’s time to experiment](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/05/20/its-time-to-experiment/)

The exact cause is unknown but the workaround is to opt out of WiX's WaitForCostingDlg dialog.

Comment: I guess this is solution I was looking for. I've repeated install/uninstall cycle many times after providing fix described in your link and everything works perfect :) Big thnx!